# Vim 7.4 installed but executes Vim 7.3 when running

Tags: macos, vim

I have installed Vim-7.4 on my OS X El Capitan. Just to make sure, executing `brew install vim` and `brew install vim --override-system-vi` returned the message:

```
Warning: vim-7.4.1952 already installed
```

However, executing vim in the terminal still throws `YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim 7.3.598+` and within vim `:version` reported:

`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Apr  5 2016 14:53:37)` and so on.

My question is almost identical to [this](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/47643) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/630911/vi-command-doesnt-open-newly-installed-vim-7-4-on-os-x), but running `hash -r` and restarting a new shell did not fix the problem (also, `which vim` shows `/usr/bin/vim`, but executing `/usr/bin/vim` gets me the same YouCompleteMe unavailable message indicting incompatible Vim), hence I think the problem is different.

PS. I also suspect the behavior has something to do with my system found Vim-7.3 and executed it before it found Vim-7.4. [Here](http://www.prioritized.net/blog/upgrading-vim-on-os-x) is where I got my idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the version that `homebrew` installs, and that resides in `/usr/local/bin`. So you either need to use:

```
/usr/local/bin/vim
```

or set your PATH so that `/usr/local/bin` appears **before** `/usr/bin`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

whereby the latter is preferable and should be done in your login script in `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: I successfully activated Vim-7.4 following your instruction, thank you.

Can you elaborate on the login script more? Like where to put it (just "cd" and then create ".profile") and what to put in (the export line)?

Comment: Check first if you have any other login scripts `cd; ls -la` and look for anything starting with a dot (period) and containing "profile", or "bash*profile" or "login". If you have one, append to it esle create ".profile" with the `export` as above. Start a new Terminal with Cmd-N to test it works.